# find the people who are friends with all of my friends

Tags: sql, oracle

the table is

```
CREATE TABLE ESTAMI(
    IDUTILISATEUR NUMBER NOT NULL,
    IDAUTREUTILISATEUR NUMBER NOT NULL,
    DATELIAISON DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINTS FK_AMI_UTI FOREIGN KEY (IDUTILISATEUR) REFERENCES UTILISATEUR,
    CONSTRAINTS FK_AMI_AUTRE_UTI FOREIGN KEY (IDAUTREUTILISATEUR) REFERENCES UTILISATEUR(IDUTILISATEUR)
);
```

where idutilisateur is user_id and idautreutilisateur is friend_id

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hierarchical query, similar to:

```
WITH cteTree
  AS (SELECT IDUTILISATEUR, IDAUTREUTILISATEUR, LEVEL AS LVL
        FROM ESTAMI
        CONNECT BY IDUTILISATEUR = PRIOR IDAUTREUTILISATEUR
        START WITH IDUTILISATEUR IN (SELECT DISTINCT IDUTILISATEUR
                                       FROM ESTAMI))
SELECT DISTINCT IDAUTREUTILISATEUR
  FROM cteTree
  WHERE LVL = 2 AND
        IDAUTREUTILISATEUR IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY 1
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8f2ff0341e79f607d1080a0f91898c4)

Comment: I get this error: ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data

Comment: Use `CONNECT BY NOCYCLE` instead, then.